# Issue with React-native share extension with cocoapods for firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to implement a share extension with a firebase-based app. So I have created a pod file and generated a .xcworkspace project.

I'm using [react-native-share-extension][1]. Followed all installation tutorial and all seem ok, but when I try to launch the extension Xcode console says:

```
RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects 'Podfile' and have run 'pod install'.
```

This is my pod file:

```
target 'Together' do
  # Pods for Together
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  pod "QBImagePickerController"

end

target 'TogetherShareEx' do

  # Pods for TogetherShareEx
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

And this my TogetherShareEx.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ReactNativeShareExtension.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import <Firebase.h>

@interface TogetherShareEx : ReactNativeShareExtension
@end

@implementation TogetherShareEx

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (UIView*) shareView {

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [FIRApp configure];

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"TogetherShareEx"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = nil;

  return rootView;
}

@end
```

I have also added these:

- added '$(inherited)' in Other Linker Flags
- added '$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase' in Header Search Paths

The result is that extension is created but when I try to share something, nothing happens. On Debugging the extension with Xcode the log shows the error shown above.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue

Comment: Somebody help us! :)

Comment: For now I dropped Firebase and made the Share Extension as light as possible. Passing data to the main app through https://github.com/alinz/react-native-swiss-knife (which uses NSUserDefaults under the hood).

Comment: I can't omit firebase, it's needed to auth, storage files and info on firestore :(

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. After installing Firebase, everything works as expected in the main app, but the share extension no longer mounts. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working after following the standard installation instructions, make sure you do the following:

1. Link `libRNFirebase.a` in your Extension's Build Phases. Also, make sure that `libPods-{YOUR_EXTENSION_NAME}.a` is linked as well.
2. Set the GoogleService-Info.plist target for both your main app
   and your share extension in the right panel.
3. In your share extension's Build Settings > Other Linker Flags,
   make sure you add $(inherited)
4. **In your Share Extension `.m` file, make sure you import
   Firebase and configure it there as well!**

For more info, see the following GitHub thread: https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension/issues/79